# A Final Model in the Cross-Validation

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have always thought that the purpose of cross-validation is creating test sets within the training test so that I can avoid over-fitting and find an aggregated model that performs better in the test set. Is this correct?

However, for instance, in the R package tidymodels, `fit_resamples()` does not provide an output in terms of the model. Then, what is the benefit of cross-validation in this case in terms of prediction in the test set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross validation has two important use cases:

- To tune hyper-parameters (or more generally model selection): dataset is split into train/test and the CV is performed inside the train. When the best model is selected wrt CV performance, a final model is fit over the whole training data using the best model/hyperparameter set. This model is evaluated on the test set.
- To evaluate future performance: Typically, if the dataset is small, we don't prefer using a separate test set and try to reduce the variance of the test performance measurement by doing CV on the evaluation step, e.g. leave one out CV. If this process follows a model selection step, then we use nested CV. But, in the end, you won't have a final model, but a better estimate of future test performance.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

So, if I understand correctly, I can use cross-validation for two purposes:

1-) Evaluate the same model/algorithm with different parameters, and choose the best performing algorithm to predict the test set.
2-) Evaluate different models/algorithms and choose the best performing model to predict the test set.

Comment: I'm sure CV is being used for some other related purposes in many research papers, but these are the two important and common usages of it.  2) Correct, 1) evaluate the same model/algorithm with different datasets (because training fold is changing, of course the parameters as well).